# How can i a confirm dialog with input on sweetalert2?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

```js
function order(id){
     const { value: numberinput } = await Swal.fire({
        title: 'You are ordering' + id + 'are you sure?' ,
        text: 'When you press the "Order!" button, your order will be processed.',
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonColor: '#3bc42b',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        confirmButtonText: 'Order!',
        reverseButtons: true,
        input: 'number',
        inputLabel: 'portion size: \n ‍',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Enter portion',
        inputAttributes: {
            min: 1,
            max: 20,
            step: 1
        },
        inputValue: 1,
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Your order has taken!',
        text: 'Your order of ${numberinput} portions is being prepared',
        icon: 'success',
        confirmButtonText: 'OK!'
    })
  } else if (result.isDismissed)
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Abandoned!',
        text: 'Your order of ${numberinput} servings has been abandoned',
        icon: 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'OK!'
        })
})
}
```

this is not working and there is a swal2 example:

```js
const ipAPI = '//api.ipify.org?format=json'

const inputValue = fetch(ipAPI)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => data.ip)

const { value: ipAddress } = await Swal.fire({
  title: 'Enter your IP address',
  input: 'text',
  inputLabel: 'Your IP address',
  inputValue: inputValue,
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: (value) => {
    if (!value) {
      return 'You need to write something!'
    }
  }
})

if (ipAddress) {
  Swal.fire(`Your IP address is ${ipAddress}`)
}
```

i guess the problem is i didn't write if (numberinput) but i dont know how can i write if(number) and if(result.isConfirmed)/if(result.isDismissed) together.Can anyone help me? i tried a lot of things but i failed.

Comment: `fetch(ipAPI)` is asynchronous, not sure how you expect to use the vale from it. There is no await so you are not grabbing the returned value from the fetch

Comment: Don't mix `await` and `.then()`

Comment: @epascarello He's not, he copied that from https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples as an example of how to get input using sweetalert2.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `.then()` when you're using `await`. `await` will return the result of `Swal.fire()`, and you can then write ordinary synchronous code to use that result. This will allow you to use the variables that are assigned from that result.

```js
async function order(id) {
  const {
    value: numberinput,
    isConfirmed,
    isDismissed
  } = await Swal.fire({
    title: 'You are ordering ' + id + ' are you sure?',
    text: 'When you press the "Order!" button, your order will be processed.',
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonColor: '#3bc42b',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    confirmButtonText: 'Order!',
    reverseButtons: true,
    input: 'number',
    inputLabel: 'portion size: \n ‍',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Enter portion',
    inputAttributes: {
      min: 1,
      max: 20,
      step: 1
    },
    inputValue: 1,
  })

  if (isConfirmed) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Your order has taken!',
      text: `Your order of ${numberinput} portions is being prepared`,
      icon: 'success',
      confirmButtonText: 'OK!'
    })
  } else if (isDismissed) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Abandoned!',
      text: `Your order has been abandoned`,
      icon: 'error',
      confirmButtonText: 'OK!'
    })
  }
}

order(123);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules. i get this error.

Comment: You need to declare `order` to be `async`. Didn't you get the same error from your original code? I just copied that from the question.

Comment: yeah i edited it here and there was an error i will solve it

Comment: i fixed it by typing async function but its not worked. The number entered as input needs to be written, but it says ${numberinput}

Comment: Template literals must be surrounded with backticks, not single quotes.

Comment: Oh wait, you're trying to use the variable in the `.then()` functions, but it's not set until they return.

Comment: Finally, it writes undefined instead of the number entered in the input, how do i solve this?Thank you for your help and good will.

Comment: You get the number when you place an order. When you cancel, SweetAlert2 doesn't return the input values, so you can't display it.

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't see it edited, everything works fine, thank you again for your help and goodwill